# Protractor: find hidden input element by attribute value

Tags: protractor

How do I go about locating & getting a value for an element like the following?

```
<input type="hidden" title="username" value="joe.doe">
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: What test are you trying to do after the element found? Test if element present? or Test the value?

Comment: @LeoGallucci - both, check if present & make sure the value is correct

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var userNameElm = $('input[title=username]');

it('is present but invisible', function() {
    expect(userNameElm.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(userNameElm.isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
});

it('should have proper value attribute', function() {
    expect(userNameElm.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('joe.doe');
});
```

Comment: I was not aware that you can use jQuery with Protractor.

Comment: That's not jQuery, Protractor `$()` is an alias for `element(by.css())`

Comment: i dont even see by.css() in the protractor api anymore, what's happening here? http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy

Comment: Try http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css or http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access an element with `data-*` attributes as we would do in `Bootstrap`, we can select such elements as follows:-

`var loginBtn = $('a[data-target="#login-modal"]');`

This is same as the accepted answer except that it has `""` around `#login-modal`.  Without the `""`, it doesn't work.

Good Luck.